# how do i display a date by adding a few months to it

Tags: php, strtotime

if i have a date 10/10/2009 and i wanted to add strtotime(+# months) to display an expiration date?

the 10/10/2009 is a start date which is imputed by the customer and the +# months is how ever many months were added for a specific product to display the expiration date.

how would i add the two to find the expiration date?

Answer (score 3):

[This tutorial](http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/2009/01/06/php-adding-and-subtracting-dates/) helped me with exactly this kind of problem recently.

```
$date = "2009-10-10";
$newdate = strtotime ("$date +3 month") ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $newdate );

echo $newdate;
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the secondary strtotime(): `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2009-10-10 + 3 months'));` yields '2010-01-10'.

Comment: Thanks! I'm leaving one extra step so as to make it less perlgolfy.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the expiration date like this:

$months = 4;                  //Replace with your own months

$expirationDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("10-10-2009 +$months month"));