# PHP date; How to find the next year?

Tags: php

I want to get today's date + one year. How do I achieve this with PHP's date functions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i display a date by adding a few months to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722442/how-do-i-display-a-date-by-adding-a-few-months-to-it)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
echo date('Y', strtotime('+1 year'));
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`strtotime`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
$date = '2010-09-16';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+12 months $date"));
// 2011-09-16
```

<sub>*On a sidenote: DateTime questions like this have been answered over and over again, so you could have found how to add to a date easily by [using the search function](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=add+months+to+date+php).*</sub>

Answer (score 7):

From PHP's [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php):

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime($your_supposed_date);
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

Gordon's much cleaner version (Thank you!):

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime("+12 months $theDate");
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: While correct and good, note that `DateTime::__construct` uses the same parsing mechanism as `strtotime`, so you can also do `$date = new DateTime("+12 months $theDate"); echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";`

Answer (score 1):

```
$Ad_year = 2015-10-20
<?php echo $Ad_year + 1?>
Result 2016
```

Comment: @TobSpr, But it does.  I don't know if it works until I try it.  But it does attempt to answer the question.  What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

The shortest version:

```php
echo (int)date('Y') + 1;
```

Comment: Hint: Typecasting is not necessary.

Comment: If you want to be strict, you will get this error `Binary operation "+" between string and 1 results in an error.`: https://phpstan.org/r/9f0842d1-8097-4dfd-a986-010a6e85670b

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new Datetime and Datetime_Intervall-classes introduced in the later PHP 5-versions.

I once posted an answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108591/calculate-number-of-hours-between-2-dates-in-php/3108800#3108800). Maybe it helps you :)

The advantage is, that this classes also checks for leap-seconds and leap-years, timezones, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with timestamps

```
echo time()+60*60*24*365
```

Answer (score 0):

Best and easy solution...
You can change month or year or day.

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+1 day +2months +1 year"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code also return next year from current date:

`<?php echo date('Y', strtotime('+12 month'));>`